# How to add Textview,spinner,button dynamically to layout without using listview and layout should be in scroll view

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, android-spinner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM8G3.png)   I want to display names of the food,quantity and amount dynamically 
 with scroll view please help me list of the food item coming from backed if i use list view to display the list scroll view not working i need to create the view dynamically based on the size of the list

Image Example

[image]

Comment: You can't use listview inside scrollview. Just use normal list view with custom adatper and add footer to show total items and Amount.

Comment: @dhuma1981 below the screen i have some more fields like apply coupons and grand total with buttons so i should need scroll view to see all the fields

Comment: The constructor for almost every android view just need a context, usually "this" when inside Activity whats the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the best way of doing this is using a ListView with a custom adapter.

You can create a layout containing your buttons, place it at the bottom and tell your list to be "above" your "buttons layout".